# Class.forName with instance checks in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to use instance checks (i.e. `x is String` checks in Kotlin) when using `Class.forName()`? I want to apply this to a class that is only available at runtime, not at compile time.

MWE:

```
val x = "banana"
val specialClass = Class.forName("org.company.specialclass.at.runtime")

x is specialClass
```

However, I get unresolved reference on specialClass. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `isInstance` may help:

```
Class.forName("java.lang.String").isInstance("txt") //true
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)) you can find the documentation for `isInstance`.

Comment: True, though I do not have the class I'd like to use at compile time, only at runtime. Therefore, I was looking for something similar like `Class.forName()`

Comment: see edit: Class.forName("java.lang.String").kotlin.isInstance("")

Comment: Nice, this approach works in the MWE. I'll check later if it works for my real use case. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: `Class` already has `isInstance`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object). No need for `.kotlin` call.

Comment: Thanks for the hint